# html ismap not showing coordinates

Tags: html

I am taking an html course on udemy and the instructor has shown the following.

```
<a href="#">
<img src="html.png" width="400" height="250" ismap>
</a>
```

When he does this and then scrolls over the image it shows the coordinates in the lower left side of his screen, however when i enter the following,

```
<a href="http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Russian_Sleep_Experiment" target="new"><img title="Russian Sleep Experiment" src="http://scaredyet.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/timthumb-600x300-520x245.jpg" alt="Russian sleep experiment" align="left" width="300" height="200" ismap></a>
```

it does not show the coordinates when i scroll over it. I have been searching and i cannot find an answer to this. Thanks in advance

Edit:I also don't understand why the image is still showing even though he replaced it with a "#" 
please advise

Comment: Sounds like he is using `Paint`. HTML will not do that. `ismap` is solely to specify that the image will be used with a `map` tag. He is almost certainly using `Paint` to figure out where his coordinates need to be.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What is   paint    ? How can i make the coordinates of the image show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ismap` is used to display coordinates appended the URL when an image is clicked on.

Your code is valid, check it out in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mbpv1kyq/

When you click the image you will be directed the image's original site with the (x, y) coordinates you clicked on appended to the end of the URL as such:

```
http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Russian_Sleep_Experiment?96,58
```

The **96,58** would be where you clicked.

As to

> When he does this and then scrolls over the image it shows the coordinates in the lower left side of his screen

He most likely using `Paint` or another similar program to read of the coordinates when he hovers **or** he has set up some `JavaScript` function to read of the current mouse coordinates. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od6Pb.png) is a screenshot of `Paint`, you can see the coordinates in the bottom left.

As to

> I also don't understand why the image is still showing even though he replaced it with a "#"

The `#` symbol is normally used for in-page links. It will not make the `img` disappear, but it will break your link when you click on it because it doesn't reference anything.

Here are some references to help you better understand `ismap`:

[W3 ismap](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_ismap.asp)

[tutorialspoins ismap](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/using_html_ismap.htm)

Comment: Alright thanks for replying, i will keep practicing.

Comment: No problem. Just remember to upvote any answers that helped you or answered your questions. Welcome to SO.

Comment: upvoted. i need a reputation of 15 before my votes are publicly visible though

Answer (score 1):

Hello everyone i have resolved the problem of not seeing the coordinates in the lower left hand corner by switching my browser from chrome to IE. Try that if you are having the same issue